# What are examples of frame operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, frame-theory

A sequence of distinct vectors $\{f_1,f_2,...\}$ belonging to a separable Hilbert space $H$ is said to be a Frame if there exist positive contants $A$, $B$ such that, for $A<B$ and for all $f\in H$:
$$A\|f\|^2\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(f,f_n)|^2\leq B \|f\|^2, \ \ \ (\ast)$$
An operator $T$ on $H$ is said "frame operator" of frame $\{f_1,f_2,...\}$, if
$$Tf=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f,f_n) f_n$$
By this the $(\ast)$ becomes,
$$A\|f\|^2\leq (Tf,f)\leq B \|f\|^2$$

This is all true in theory, but I've never seen a practical example of frame and, above all frame operator. I emphasize: especially examples of frame operators. Because while I can imagine an example of frame (a set of generators linearly dependent), I can not find an example of frame operator.

They are like answers containing examples and references (books, papers, websites).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main use of the frame operator is to prove things about frames. In applications, the analysis and synthesis operators, i.e. $A : H \to \ell^2, x \mapsto (\langle x, f_n \rangle)_n$ and $S : \ell^2 \to H, (\alpha_n)_n \mapsto \sum_n \alpha_n f_n$ are much more important. For example, if your frame is tight, then $T$ will just be a multiple of the identity, which is not a very interesting operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a frame operator depends of course on the frame. For a frame $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in a Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$, the frame operator $S : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is, as you mentioned, just defined as
$$ S f = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \langle f, f_n \rangle f_n.    \quad \quad (*)$$
To my knowledge, this is the only form in which you can write the frame operator for abstract frames. To obtain "an example of a frame operator", you just plug in the elements $f_n$ of the frame.

The situation is different for "concrete" frames. For example, a *Gabor frame* for $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ is a collection of the form $\{e^{2 \pi i b x} g(x-ak)\}_{k,n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $g \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$, that forms a frame for $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$. For such a frame, the frame operator becomes, by definition,
$$ [S f](x) =  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i b x} \overline{g(x-ak)} d\mu(x) \bigg) e^{2 \pi i b x} g(x-ak). $$
One can show, by assuming several conditions, that this frame operator can be re-written as
$$[Sf](x) = \frac{1}{b} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x - \frac{n}{b}) \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} g(x-ak) \overline{g(x - ak - \frac{n}{b})}, $$
which is known as the *Walnut representation* in Gabor analysis.

An excellent book on frame theory is *An Introduction to Frames and Riesz Bases* by Ole Christensen. The first half of that book considers "abstract" frames in general Hilbert spaces; the second half of that book considers "concrete" frames in mainly the Hilbert space $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy finite-dimensional example:

Consider the frame $\{u_1\equiv (1,0)^T, u_2\equiv (0,1)^T, u_3\equiv(1,1)^T\}\subset\mathbb R^2$. The associated *frame operator* $S$ can be written in dyadic notation as $S\equiv\sum_{k=1}^3 u_k u_k^\dagger$, with $u_k^\dagger$ dual vector to $u_k$, and thus, as a matrix,
$$S= \begin{pmatrix}2& 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
You can then for example notice how this has the eigenvalues $1,3$, which are in fact the frame bounds of the considered frame. The associated eigenvectors are $v_1\equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1,-1)^T$ and $v_3\equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1,1)^T$, respectively, and one can observe how these two vectors correspond to vectors of coefficients with norm equal to the respective eigenvalues: writing $v=\sum_{k=1}^3 c_k(v) u_k$, where $c_k(v)=\langle S^{-1}u_k,v\rangle$, we get
$$\boldsymbol{c}(v_1) =\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\\ 0\end{pmatrix} \implies \|\boldsymbol{c}(v_1)\|^2=1, \\
\boldsymbol{c}(v_3) =\frac1{3\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix} \implies \|\boldsymbol{c}(v_3)\|^2=\frac13.$$
This is in line with the general fact that decomposing an eigenvector of $S$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ as a linear combination of the frame elements gives back a vector of coefficients with norm $1/\lambda$. To see it, suppose $Sv=\lambda v$ and $(u_k)_k$ are the frame elements. Then
$$c_k(v) = \langle S^{-1}u_k,v\rangle=\frac1{\lambda}\langle u_k,v\rangle\implies \|\boldsymbol c(v)\|^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}\langle v,Sv\rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$